# Disable field on focus with jquery

Tags: jquery, select, input, focus

I try to create a jquery code, which do the following:

If I take the field with the id "ac_inp" in focus, the select field with id "ac_sel" goes disabled. And if I take the select field with the id "ac_sel" in focus, the field with id "ac_inp" goes disabled. But it doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#ac_inp").is(':focus')) {
        $("#ac_inp").prop('disabled', false)
        $("#ac_sel").prop('disabled', true)
    }
    if ($("#ac_sel").is(':focus')) {
        $("#ac_inp").prop('disabled', true)
        $("#ac_sel").prop('disabled', false)
    }
});
```

Comment: attach to event.. this will only happen on load

Comment: `$( "#target" ).focus(function() {
  //you code here
});` like this one

Comment: that means? do you have an example for me?

Comment: given above place you conditional statement in `your code part`

Comment: if you can add the html mark i can help more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your snippet you prepare a script that runs once at document load time.

In this event you need to create events for the focus, not a single check that never run anymore.

If you have this basic doubts, please consider to study an entry level book before start coding, seriously or you will waste a lot of time and it is really important to understand the base concepts.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#ac_inp").focus(function() {
     $(this).prop('disabled', false);
     $("#ac_sel").prop('disabled', true);
  });

  $("#ac_sel").focus(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
    $("#ac_inp").prop('disabled', true);
  });

});
</script>
```